# How is a 256 bin HSV histogram quantised?

Tags: color

I am doing some research on the ScalableColor descriptor in MPEG-7 and I came across this passage:

> The descriptor extractions starts with the computation of the colour
>   historgam with 25 bins in the HSV colour space with the Hue (H)
>   component quantised to 16 bins, and Saturation (S) and Value (V)
>   quantised to 4 bins each.

My statistics is a little rusty so could someone please explain (hopefully with an example) how the bins are quantised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantisation is simply a transformation from a large range of possible values into a smaller range of possible values.

In the HSV colour space, **H**‌ue takes values from 0 to 360 degrees, while **S**‌aturation and **V**‌alue take values from 0 to 1. I believe (though I'm not positive) that for this process in Mpeg7 the quantisation is **uniform**, which would mean:

To get our Hue from a range of 0-360 into 16 bins, we would simply divide by `360/16`, or `22.5`, and then round down. So:

```
Hue    Quantised
0      0
22     0
23     1
44     1
45     2
...
337    14
338    15
359    15
```

(One minor quibble: We need to map a hue of 360 to 0 before starting)

For Saturation and Value, we need to get from a range of reals in 0-1 into 4 bins, so we divide by `1/4`, or `0.25`, and round down:

```
Value   Quanitised
0       0
0.24    0
0.25    1
0.49    1
0.5     2
0.74    2
0.75    3
1.0     3
```

(Here we have to make a call on rounding the quarter points)

In general, to quantise uniformly from a range of x-y into n bins, each bin gets a slice of width `(y-x) / n` in the original range.

You'd need to check the mpeg7 spec for whether this quantisation is to be carried out uniformly, though.